# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' from using a list generated from CSV and SET

Tags: python, csv, set

I have a list called `eligible[]` generated from csv:

```
with open('C:\emp.csv', newline='') as f:
    eligible = []
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        eligible.append(row)
```

I'm trying to create a new list removing duplicates from one created in a regular `for` loop.

I typed them both and they show up as `list`s.

I get this error when trying to remove duplicates using `set`:

```
new_eligible = list(set(small)^set(eligible))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I tried to turn them both into `set`s but it gives me an error.

Comment: `eligeble` is a *list of lists*; each element in the list is itself a list. What did you expect to intersect here? Is there just one column in each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out by the great minds, you're getting the error because `eligible` is a `list` whose elements are `list`s. That's because each row in a `csv.reader` is a `list` corresponding to the Comma Separated Values read on each logical line.

A simple workaround is to convert each row returned into a `tuple` before appending it to `eligible`. This is because `tuple`s can be `set` elements. You can also create it more compactly by using something called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
with open('emp.csv', newline='') as f:
    eligible = [tuple(row) for row in csv.reader(f)]
```

You'll need the other list of things you don't want duplicated to also contain elements which are `tuple`s. You can either change the way it's created or convert it afterwards like this:

```
small_set = set(tuple(elem) for elem in small)
```

Lastly, to create a new list that doesn't have any elements in another, I think you should use the regular set difference operator, `-`, rather than the one for the symmetric-difference, `^`:

```
new_eligible = list(set(eligible) - small_set)
```

Answer (score 0):

`eligible` is a *list of lists*: ie it is a list of rows, and each row is itself a list. As the elements are themselves lists, they cannot be hashed so the entire list cannot be turned into a list.

It's pretty hard to understand what you are trying to do here: are you perhaps trying to filter out any rows from eligible that equal the `small` list? In which case you need to compare them before adding them to a list:

```
small_set = set(small)
with open('C:\emp.csv', newline='') as f:
    eligible = []
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if set(eligible) != small_set:
            eligible.append(row)
```

Comment: Great minds think alike; note the start of my comment and your answer.